# How to overwrite the entire 'front' tab with values from the 'data' tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

While there a few ways to [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13605213/4531180) over a spreadsheet, here using [sample](https://spreadsheet.dev/iterate-through-rows-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script) code:

```
function onOpen(e) {

  menuItems();
}

function menuItems() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('iterate', 'iterateThroughRows')
    .addToUi();
}

function iterateThroughRows() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("data");
  var front = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("front sheet");
  var values = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  values.forEach(function (row) {
    Logger.log(row);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(row);
    //front.getRange().setValues();  //setRange? delete all data first?
  });
}
```

So far as it goes, this works in that an alert pops up showing the data.  Looking to overwrite the entire `front page` sheet with all data from the `data` sheet.  How is it **specified** to write the `values` to the `front` sheet?

*For the sake of simplicity, only concerned with data and not formulas or formatting.*

Answer (score 2):

To replace the contents of the '`front`' sheet with the values in the '`data`' sheet, use `Sheet.clearContents()`, `Sheet.getDataRange()`, `Range.offset()`, `Range.getValues()` and `Range.setValues()`, like this:

```
function replaceFrontSheetContentsWithDataSheetValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const frontSheet = ss.getSheetByName('front sheet');
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  const values = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  frontSheet
    .clearContents()
    .getDataRange()
    .offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Copy all of the sheets of a spreadsheet to the first sheet

```
function copysstosh() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tsh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  tsh.clearContents();
  tsh.appendRow([`Spreadsheet Copy: ${new Date()}`]);
  ss.getSheets().filter((s,i) => i != 0).forEach(sh => {
    let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  });
}
```